# Terminal and putStrLn output difference

Tags: haskell

Whe I type out into terminal the code below, it can successfully display all the detail I need.

```
avg "Vivo" testDatabase
```

But when I try to show that it works with the code below, it gives me an error - It couldn't match type 'Float' with '[Char]'. How should I try to fix this error?

```
--the function for code
avg :: String -> [Spa] -> Float
avg avgAreaRating spas = fromIntegral (sum lvlrating) /  fromIntegral (length lvlrating)
  where area = spaArea avgAreaRating spas
        lvlrating = concatMap getLevelRating area 

--code
show 5  = putStrLn $ avg "Vivo" testDatabase
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[putStrLn](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) needs a `String` as its argument. Your error occurs because you are calling it on a `Float` - if the types don't match, your code won't compile.

The reason it works when you just put `avg "Vivo" testDatabase` into GHCi is that GHCi automatically and implicitly calls [print](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) on anything you pass to it. Unlike `putStrLn`, `print` can take as argument any type which can be converted to a string (via the `Show` typeclass - which always includes `Float`).

So all you need to do is replace `putStrLn` with `print`:

```
print $ avg "Vivo" testDatabase
```